# preg_replace for replacing number value in string

Tags: php, preg-replace

Launguage used PHP
TimeString = 1500-1550

I want to use preg_replace to change the 1550 half of the string to 1530.  I tried to use a pattern of `(/d|/d/d)50`  Where I am getting stuck is I don't know how to use the replacement feature to change any /d50 or /d/d50 to have a 30 suffix.   I don't want to sue str replace in php as it will change the first time 1500 to 130 since the 50 matches.  Any ideas?

Comment: You mean `\d` instead of `/d`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here..

```
<?php
    $numbers = array (1500, 1550, 140, 150, 15000);
    foreach ($numbers as $number) {
        echo preg_replace('/(\d|\d\d)50\b/', '${1}30', $number);
        echo "\n";
    }
?>
```

Will return:

```
1500
1530
140
130
15000
```

Comment: site won't  let me upvote until I build my reputation otherwise I would.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To match digits you need to use `\d`. Not `/d`.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(\d\d)50/', '${1}30', $string)
```